# Error al instalar SQL Server Managment 2008 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ya probé todo y no tuve éxito con la instalación, así que acudo a ustedes a ver si me pueden ayudar.

**Problema:** No se puede instalarSQL Server Managment 2008 Express.

**Error:** 
"Error 1911.Could not register type library for file C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Help\hxds.dll.  Contact your support personnel."

**Sistema Operativo**: Windows server 2008 SP2

Ya probé con todo lo que se encuentra en la Web. Desistale el paquete KB3072630 de Windows Update, desistalé y actualicé todo pero sin éxito.

El motor de SQL Server 2008 Express se instala sin problemas. Solo tengo problemas con el Managment tool.

Aparentemente el error sale cuando se quiere instalar: SQLEXPRWT_x64_ESN\x64\setup\trin_aide.msi - Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2.0

Aclaro que estoy con el usuario Administrador.

Comment: Cumple tu equipo los requerimientos? dices que desistalastes la KB3072630 y que luego has vuelto a actualizar, ¿La has vuelto a instalar? Por otra parte has probado a registrar tu mismo la dll y luego hacer la instalación?

Comment: Hola Miguel. Gracias por tu respuesta. El equipo cumple todos los requerimientos y pasa todas la validaciones del instalador de SQL.
Con respecto a la KB3072630. La desistalé, reinicié el sistema y probé instalar de nuevo el managment tools y me da error. Al no  poder instalarlo, volví a instalar el paquete de seguridad.
No probé registrar la dll porque son varias las que dan errores. Si omito la primera, me aparecen varias más.
Alguna idea? Gracias

Comment: el SQl que instalas que versión es? el SQL server que quieres instalar está en el mismo idioma que tu Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Leyendo en foros, con la desintalación del paquete KB3072630 debería funcionarte, en caso de no ser así veo que otra solución es copiar la dll **dte90.olb** de otro equipo y reemplazándola. Te dejo un [enlace](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/95548bb2-ac2a-4a2c-843f-09210b0fc06e/error-1911-while-installing-sql-server-2012-client-tools-on-windows-server-2008-service-pack-2?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade) donde puedes encontrar una mejor guía respecto a dicha solución (Error 1911). Espero te ayude en algo mi respuesta. Saludos.